# Ошибка при сортировки RecyclerView из DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, сортировка, recyclerview, dialogfragment

Есть `RecyclerView` с `item`, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на `LinerLayout`, открывался `DialogFragment` и в нём был `ImageView`, по нажатию на `ImageView` сортировался мой `RecyclerView`. Как исправить ошибку?

Так как сделал я, не работает, при нажатии на `ImageView`, приложение крашиться с ошибкой:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String[] com.example.test.Attraction.FragmentAttractionRecyclerView.mArraysNames' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.sortArray_type(DialogSort.java:36)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.DialogSort.lambda$onCreateView$0$DialogSort(DialogSort.java:29)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.-$$Lambda$DialogSort$hNUzI3gzFGpf0diQdPCF44sgutU.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
```

`Fragment` в котором находиться `RecyclerView` и `LinerLayout`.

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentAttractionRecyclerView";
    private RecyclerView mRec;
    public AdapterAttractions adapter;
    public ArrayList<ItemAttractions> exampleList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public String[] mArraysNames = new String[]{"Baby островок", "Виражи", "Вокруг света", "5D кинотеатр"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            }
        };

        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "LongLogTag"})
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();
        LinearLayout dialog_button = requireView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);

        dialog_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog");
            DialogSort dialog = new DialogSort();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogSort");
        });

        SearchView searchView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽", 0));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Интерактивный", "80₽", 1));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽", 2));
        exampleList.add(new ItemAttractions(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽", 3));
    }

    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
        adapter = new AdapterAttractions(exampleList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`DialogFragment` в котором находится `ImageView` по нажатию на которую должен сортироваться `RecyclerView` из `FragmentAttractionRecyclerView`.

```
public class DialogSort extends DialogFragment  {
    FragmentAttractionRecyclerView fragmentAttractionRecyclerView;
    ImageView img;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sort, container, false);
        img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            {
                sortArray_type();
                sortArrayList_type();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    private void sortArray_type() {
        Arrays.sort(fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.mArraysNames);
        fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private void sortArrayList_type() {
        Collections.sort(fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.exampleList, (o1, o2) -> o1.get_attraction_type().compareTo(o2.get_attraction_type()));
        fragmentAttractionRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас в диалоге только одна картинка будет вызывать событие сортировки?

Comment: @Crush да, по нажатию будет происходить сортировка

Comment: Возможно, тогда картинку перенести в фрагмент и там сортировать или использование диалога принципиально? =)